# Data Modeling and implementing relationships [1 to many][many to many] etc

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, relation

I am learning about data modelling using `MYSQL`. Currently, I am working on a model that shows relationships with different entities, I am hoping someone would be kind enough to share any thoughts/opinions on how I can improve my models' relationships. I have been getting confused with the different relationships, and hope that anyone can point out errors.

Ps: I will be normalizing the table in the future, but this is just a question on my relationships with this current set up.

**Additional information about the graphic:**

1. the light bulb represents PRIMARY KEYS
2. the red mark represents FOREIGN KEYS

*Image designed by me*
[image: Image of my data model]

Comment: Why is one relationship line solid and the others dotty?

Comment: Im not sure why they came out like that

Comment: What confuses you about relationships? (Not in the interpersonal.stackexchange.com sense :) )